# mysql_query() executes correctly on 2nd time

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I want to update value in db using mysql_query(). I create new customer, then if I want to update his name (or other values), it fails! So, first time only. If I refresh site with the same url, it works. Same code doesn't work first time, and second time it works. My question is whyyy?

Connect to db is first step, when website loads.

```
@mysql_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS) or die (mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db(DBNAME) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

Next step is UPDATE (in this example id is hardcoded)

```
$meno_z2=$_POST['firstnameko'];
$sql31888 = "UPDATE fitko_customer SET meno='".$meno_z2."' WHERE id=63";
mysql_query($sql31888)  or die ('Error updating database: ' . mysql_error());
```

EDIT:
Again, my code works. But for some reason it doesn't work at first time. 2nd, 3rd,.. time it works perfect!
What other code do you need? First is connect, Second is mysql_query part. Here is all needed code:
http://pastebin.com/itN6PURw

Comment: try using this  : `$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

               if (!$conn) {
                   die("Connection failed");
               }

               $sql = "your update query";

               $result = $conn->query($sql);`

Comment: hard to say without seeing full code. You sure you're not running a conditional statement and/or a function somewhere and/or JS/Ajax and not showing us?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh why should they try that? Re-read the question again. Plus they're using `mysql_` which works for them.

Comment: Please provide more code;  typically this occurs if you've already called a statement, and the update is starting with the second row.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : just for the testing purpose to see whether the code runs or not as expected

Comment: I edited question with more details
@AbhishekGhosh I tried but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

No reason to use `@` in front of those method calls. Its the error suppress operator and you are suppressing any potential errors that are arising. Please try without the `@`.

Comment: the question is unclear and this to be honest, is more a comment really.

Comment: Okay sorry I'll delete it.